# Jquery + Knockoutjs GUI animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Well i have been trying to make a gui component that will slide up when you move your mouse to the bottom of the page http://jsfiddle.net/62u3A/4/ but it does not work so well does any one have a good idea how to make it work better?

Comment: I think my original answer is incorrect (I deleted it), you should use mouseenter/mouseleave, and stop.show/stop.hide to resume animation after value change - http://jsfiddle.net/62u3A/9/  (show/hide are required to ensure slide will start - it won't start if element is in wrong visibility state)

Comment: mouseleave seems to do a much better job that mouseout! thanks for the tip ill try it out a bit more when i get home but thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Add .stop() before your .slideup()

[jquery stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62u3A/5/)

Comment: That made it work better but its not right the height varies from time to time with that solution..

Answer (score 0):

As for me you've chosen wrong events to handle. I tried mouseenter/mouseleave - it looks like it works fine. Stop animation is also good idea